# I'm not sure what my job is

Tags: job-description

I am a product manager by title. And I know what is expected of me. I want to continue learning and get more certifications but since my title doesn't match my responsibilities I don't know what direction to go.

Background: I have worked in tech for a long time. Help desk, deskside support etc.

Now I own a product at work. It's clear what product is mine, and our team is under the same umbrella as the dev team so I thought this was going to be product management.

We don't work with the dev team at all. No product requirements, anything like that. Our products are already developed, and purchased from big name companies.

My job is to admin, and keep track of new features for the product that we pay for that our users use. help users interested in using it to make sure it's right for them, write best practices and guide people to use it in a way that would be best for their team.

I love what I do, but I feel very lost in the void since I can't put a name on it that helps me further my Career doing it.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What direction do you *want* to go? And have you discussed that with your management?

Comment: Your job is what you've been asked to do, what you're succeeding at, and what impressed your employer (and if necessary your next to interviewer), not your title.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm not sure what my job is
>
> I am a product manager by title.
>
> I can't put a name on it that helps me further my Career doing it.

The name is obviously Product Manager. And the role of Product Manager is different in many companies.

If you want something different, discuss it with your boss.